# Tools for refactoring table-based HTML layouts to CSS?

Tags: html, css, refactoring, css-tables

Given an HTML page that has a complex table-based layout and many tags that are duplicated and wasteful, e.g.:

```
td align="left" class="tableformat" width="65%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ff9600; border-right:1px solid #ff9600; background-color:#FDD69E" nowrap etc.
```

Are there tools to aide the task of refactoring the page into a more compact form? For instance, a tool that automatically generates CSS styles and selectors? That converts tables into div layouts?

Just to give a sense of the order of the problem, the page I'm looking at is >8000 lines of HTML and JavaScript, which is 500Kb *not counting* images!

---

Update: In re. "give up and start from scratch" comments. What does that mean, in the real world? Print out the page, scan it, set it as the background image in Dreamweaver, and start with that? Seriously? Would that really be more efficient than refactoring?

---

Update: I'm not denigrating "trace it from scratch" nor did I mean to imply that Dreamweaver is by any means my tool of choice. I'm just very surprised that refactoring a layout is considered to be an intractable problem.

Comment: Mayhaps you'll be better off redesiging from scratch. it seems more like you're looking for a bandaid over a horribly designed page, which might not give the best results.

Comment: I agree with the first comment - you cannot simply run a tool to recover this, especially CSS and tables are to - more or less - incompatible types of technique.

Comment: I'd like to see such a tool. If the tables are in correctly formed html, such a tool should be possible although difficult to create. I'd imagine a lot of web devs would like one for those times we have to "fix" a website initially created by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [TimB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151369/tools-for-refactoring-table-based-html-layouts-to-css#151466) in that automated tools are going to have trouble doing this, in particular making the relational jumps to combine and abstract CSS in the most efficient way.

If you are presenting tabular data, it **may** be reasonable to attempt to refactor the inline CSS to reusable classes.

If you have a lot of similar tables with inline styles you can gradually refactor the CSS by simple search and replace. 
This will give you lots of classes that match a subset of similar tables and lots of somewhat similar classes. 
Breaking this up into layout and presentation would be a good start, then overriding these with specific classes for each theme or semantically related item.

I would still recommend **starting from scratch**, it's probably going to be quicker, and you can recreate only what you need to present the page, and can reuse elements or collections of elements at a later date.

The time spent will also pay off **significantly** if the page is ever needed to be modified again.

But that's **not at all** likely is it? :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of specific tools, only the generic ones of caffeine and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which anyone doing CSS work should be aware of.

I think that the problem is sufficiently hard that automated tools would struggle to produce good, maintainable markup and CSS.

Comment: I agree, automated tools would require so much massaging of the data as to be a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are looking for more automated means of re-factoring an old table-based layout to CSS standards. However, I agree with some of the other comments to "start from scratch".

What this means to you is that you should try to rebuild (using CSS) the look that was achieved using an HTML table. If this concept escapes you, then I would suggest Googling for some beginner CSS tutorials, maybe even some focusing on teaching the concept of Table->CSS layouts..

Another tool to consider (that could possibly aid you even further) would be some sort of CSS "framework". I recommend [Blueprint CSS](http://code.google.com/p/blueprintcss/) for this, as it helps in the creation of grid/table-like layouts with minimal effort. Another good one is [Yet-Another-Multicolumn-Layout](http://www.yaml.de/en/), which has a really neat [multi-column layout builder](http://builder.yaml.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't just throw it in dreamweaver or whatever tool of choice and slice it up. Write the HTML first, in purely semantic style. eg, a very common layout would end up being:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img id="logo"/>
    <h1 id="title">
      My Site
    </h1>
    <div id="subtitle">Playing with css</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
    <p>Blah blah blah..</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Some link</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Do the HTML in a way that makes sense with your content. It should be usable if you have no CSS at all. After that, add in the CSS to make it look the way you want. With the state of browsers/CSS now, you still probably have to add some decorators to the HTML - eg, wrap some things in extra divs, just to be able to get the content the way you want.

Once you're done though, you'll have a very flexible layout that can be modified easily with CSS, and you'll have a page that is accessible, to both disabled people and search engines.

It does take quite a bit of learning before you get the knack of it, but it is worthwhile. Resist the temptation to give up and go back to table based layouts, and just work your way through. Everything can be done with semantic HTML and CSS.

Comment: Why so many divs?
Why not <ul id="menu">?
I'd also consider putting the subtitle in an h2, or even a span inside of the h1, depending.  the less "semantically null" tags the better.

Answer (score 0):

You denigrate this approach in your question, but I'd recommend taking a screen shot of your page in the browser whose rendering you like the best, declare that to be your reference, and start trying to recreate it.  It's easier than you think.  I've had to take skanky old table-based layouts and turn them into CMS templates done with modern techniques and it's not that bad a job.

Answer (score 0):

I am tackling a similar problem at the moment, not quite as messy as what this sounds, but the product of really bad asp.net web forms, overblown view state, and deeply nested server controls that format search results from a database. Resulting in ~300 - 400K of markup for 50 DB rows - yeek.

I have not found any automated tools that will do a half way reasonable job of refactoring it.

Starting with a tool like visual studio that you can use to reformat the code to a consistent manner helps. You can then use combinations of regexs and rectangular selecting to start weeding out the junk, and stripping back the redundant markup, to start to sort out what is important and what is not, and then start defining, by hand, an efficient pattern to present the information.

The trick is to break into manageable chunks, and build it up from there.

If you have a lot of actual "tabular data" to format, and is only a once off, I have found excel to be my saviour on a few occasions, paste the data into a sheet, and then use a combination of concatenate and fill to generate the markup for the tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch means going back to the design drawing board.  If you need to refactor such a monstrosity, then for all the time you will spend making it better, you might as well have done a full redesign.

If you want to get away from duplicated and wasteful tags, you need to escape Dreamewaver.  A good text editor (jedit, emacs, vim, eclipse, etc.) is really all you need.  If you customize your editor properly, you won't even miss Dreamweaver.  (Emacs with nXhtml and yasnippets is my favorite.)